# Does this random image display code load all images at once or just one image?

Tags: jquery, image, random

I purchased a website template which loads one random header image on each page visit.  I asked the developer about this snippet of code but they could not answer 100%.  If I had ten images to choose from would this code load just one image (the one displayed in the header) or would it load all ten images before displaying a random one?

```
$(function(){
    $('.head').css(
        "background-image", "url(image/header-" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + ".jpg)"
    );
});
```

Comment: That's quite easy to check in console network tab :)

Comment: I still have a hard time tying my velcro shoelaces. lol I'm only starting to learn but I will look in to console network lab.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That would load a random image. It is only choosing one.

To clarify further, the math function is randomizing the number to select which image, so the result will be a single number which will be used as the final string. So in this example it would be the equivalent of this CSS:

```
<style>
  .head{ 
     background-image: url(image/header-5.jpg); 
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Great, so I don't have to worry about the page having to load ten 100kb images before displaying the one random header image?  That's perfect, thanks very much for your quick response. *Perfect!  Thank you again, appreciate your wisdom... :)

Comment: yes, but you can always use the browser console to view the network traffic to confirm for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It will load just one of the images, because this function, on one call will just generate one single random number, (say 7) between 0 and 10 (which is 0 included and upto 9) and load the image for that number and stay quiet.

Moreover, the function, the way it is written becomes anonymous, and because it has no name, it cannot really be called again, so it will assign the background image once and just end!